# Running WSCRIPT.EXE from C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, wsh

I have a web application written in C# that needs to display a message box using WSCRIPT.EXE (from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32).

```
// Show the message in a Windows Script Message Box
ps.FileName = "wscript.exe";
ps.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", strScriptName, strCleanedAlertMessage);
ps.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(ps);
```

This works as expected on my local PC, but does not work or error when running from our development web server.

We are running IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is this possible? Do I need to configure certain security setting son the web server?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that, period.  You need to understand the difference between the server and the client.

Comment: "Expected" in this case should be "failed to show message box on non-interactive desktop" (as you see on IIS config). It "succeeded" locally only because you run it from dev server that runs under you local account on your desktop session.